# Can I deploy an entire node_modules folder as a lambda layer?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

My serverless project has a single `node_modules` folder shared by all functions. I would like to deploy this entire folder as a layer. I've tried putting this in `serverless.yml`:

```
layers:
  dependencies:
    path: node_modules
```

This doesn't work because I end up with two empty deployment packages (one for the functions and the other for the dependencies).

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `path` should point to a directory with a `package.json` and `node_modules` directory. Your repo should probably have a `layers` directory and/or some other step in the deploy flow that builds the layer. That way, your code can still reference the modules in the normal way (and your editor/plugins won't complain).